# Callback notification system

Tags: integration, square, storefront

We are interested in using Square connect to create an app that will communicate back to our ASPDotNETStorefront based store. In the documentation, I don't see any kind of notification system that would call back to us when a transaction has been made in Square. Does such a API based notification system exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Square Connect API does not currently provide notifications for events such as transactions. I will pass this use case along to the Connect API engineering team.

As an alternative solution, you can periodically send a request to the [List Payments](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#get-payments) endpoint to discover payments that have been created since your previous request. Payment information is typically available from this endpoint within a couple minutes of the payment being processed.